# Getting "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" Warning

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, php

I am on the last step in a tutorial that I followed [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-4-using-the-data/) , called "Using the data".

I tried using//

```
$album_repeatable = unserialize($post_meta_data['album_repeatable'][0]);  
        echo '[ul class="album_repeatable"]';  
        foreach ($album_repeatable as $string) {  
            echo '[li]'.$string.'[/li]';  
        }  
        echo '[/ul]';
```

But I get the Warning as stated in Question Title//

"*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()* "

What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: `$album_repeatable` is not an array.

Comment: @toscho I renamed _"custom"_ to _"album"_...

Comment: Do not unserialize the post meta field. Then try `var_export( $album_repeatable );` to inspect the value.

Comment: @toscho Thank you for the suggestion, but I am new to PHP etc so I have no idea how to do this...Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used normal method to get field data instead of "*unserialize*"

Switched this line:

```
$album_repeatable = unserialize($post_meta_data['album_repeatable'][0]);
```

to this line:

```
$album_repeatable = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'album_repeatable', true);
```

Now my repeatable field Data is being displayed.

Thanks @toscho for pointing it out...